# getting openSSL to work with Qt on mac

Tags: macos, qt, https, openssl

I am making some api calls to google maps some of which need to be encrypted so i'm using https. Whenever I make a request using https I get the errors:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_psk_client_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
```

I get these errors also when using http but I will still recieve the data I want whereas with https I don't. 
I see that this is apparently because I do not have openSSL installed, so I checked and I had version 0.9.8, so I installed a newer version (1.0.2) (Note i'm on mac) but still have the same problem. I have seen a lot of similar questions but there either wasn't a solution, or if there was one it didn't work for me or I didn't understand what to actually do.

I ran the following code:

```
     qDebug() << "Support SSL:  " << QSslSocket::supportsSsl()
                << "\nLib Version Number: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionNumber()
                << "\nLib Version String: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString()
                << "\nLib Build Version Number: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionNumber()
                << "\nLib Build Version String: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
```

and received the output:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_psk_client_callback
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
Support SSL:   true 
Lib Version Number:  9470431 
Lib Version String:  "OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015" 
Lib Build Version Number:  268439727 
Lib Build Version String:  "OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014"
```

the versions listed don't refer to the one I recently installed so could the problem be its not using the new version?

If anyone knows how to fix this so I can use https without errors please give specific instructions because i'm not very experienced.

Thanks

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. Due to the fact that Qt was built with a more recent OpenSSL version it'll try to resolve some extra function that you don't have. Besides, recent Qt versions don't even use OpenSSL on OS X, but SecureTransport. Which Qt version is that?

Comment: @peppe its version 5.5

Answer (score 1):

The SSL warnings aren't fatal; secure connections should continue to work.  According to [this closed bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43173) you can suppress these messages by setting the following environment variable:

```
QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.network.ssl.warning=false
```

Also, I'm fairly certain these warning messages (or very similar messages) appear on platforms other than OS X.