# QIODevice::read: device not open Remote JSON File QT

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5

This has driven me nuts. Been looking everywhere for a solution to this but amazingly there is very little out there about loading remote JSON files into QT.

I've got this code which works fine when I try to load a local file.

```
QFile jsonFile("/Users/blah/blah/myfile.json");


if (!jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    qDebug() << "Unable to open file, exiting...";
    return;
}

QByteArray jsonData = jsonFile.readAll();
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonData);
QJsonObject jObject = doc.object();
QVariantMap json_map = jObject.toVariantMap();

QString getNow = json_map["now"].toString();
QString getImage = json_map["image"].toString();
QString getNext = json_map["next"].toString();

ui->live1->setText(getNow);
ui->live2->setText(getImage);
ui->live3->setText(getNext);
```

But nothing I've tried for the past 5 hours will make it load a remote file and I can't find a straight up explanation showing how such a simple thing is achieved.

```
 QFile jsonFile("https://myserver.com/myfile.json");
 QUrl jsonFile("https://myserver.com/myfile.json");
```

And a whole bunch of other methods including QTextStream and anything else that I thought might do it like [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Download_Data_from_URL) which seemed way over the top for what I'm trying to do. But everything either returns...

```
 QIODevice::read: device not open
```

...Or a slew of other errors letting me know just how badly I screwed up.

Can somebody please put me out of my misery here?

** EDIT **

Using the QNetwork libs, but now throwing an `expected expression` error on the `QObject::connect` line?

```
 QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://myserver.com/myfile.json"));
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]() {
        QByteArray data = reply->readAll();

        QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);
        QJsonObject jObject = doc.object();
        QVariantMap json_map = jObject.toVariantMap();

        QString getNow = json_map["now"].toString();
        QString getImage = json_map["image"].toString();
        QString getNext = json_map["next"].toString();

        ui->live1->setText(getNow);
        ui->live2->setText(getImage);
        ui->live3->setText(getNext);

        reply->deleteLater();
    });
```

** EDIT 2 **

I just realised that I need to include the C++11 compiler

```
 CONFIG += c++11
```

But now it's just gone mental throwing SSL errors

```
 qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
 qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
 qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
 qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
 qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
 qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
 qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
```

** EDIT 3 **

Making some progress (I guess...)

It seems that QT is using an old version of SSL (which probably isn't supported according to the docs).

QDebug spat out this when asked about the SSL...

```
 Support SSL:   true
 Lib Version Number:  9470431
 Lib Version String:  "OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016"
 Lib Build Version Number:  268439727
 Lib Build Version String:  "OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014"
```

So now I need to figure out how to make QT use the newer version that's on my machine.

Comment: You need `QtNetwork` for this. `QFile` cannot open remote URLs.

Comment: Oh man.. I wish the QT documentation was a bit more noob friendly. That should have been the first thing I found when looking for this but you are the first person that I've seen mention it. So I guess it's a whole different method to import a file with <QNetwork> then?

Comment: Yes, please see my answer below for a simple example.

Comment: Yeah that is all done, QT is now complaining that my version of SSL is too old? According to terminal I'm running `OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017` which should be supported according to the QT docs?

Comment: Thanks but both of those posts are for Windows, I'm building on a Mac.

Comment: @user3717922 see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640732/getting-openssl-to-work-with-qt-on-mac

Comment: and this: https://github.com/opencor/opencor/issues/516

Answer (score 0):

`QFile` does not support remote URIs. You need to use QtNetwork for this.

The following C++11 example demonstrates how to retrieve JSON from a remote URI:

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://example.com/file.json"));
QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);

QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]() {
    QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
    // do stuff with data
    reply->deleteLater();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, so I've added the edit to the post above as it's too long for a comment, but it's throwing an `expected expression` error on the `QObject::connect` line? Sorry if I'm just being dense here...

Comment: The SSL errors are caused by a rather subtle issue. You need the OpenSSL libraries installed since Qt doesn't ship them by default (due to licensing issues). The two libraries you need are `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll`.

Comment: Any idea what they are for Mac?